# Converting dry contact to momentary switch with feedback

Tags: switches, converter, feedback, adapter

I need to adapt a fan that is turned on/off with an SPST momentary switch to also work with a dry contact. Additionally, I need to ensure that the desired fan state is reached when the dry contact state changes (contact closed=fan on; contact open=fan off). So, if a user turns on the fan while the dry contact is open, closing the contact will not turn the fan off. I can't modify the fans's circuits, so have been thinking of using a relay to pulse the momentary switch and current sensor for feedback.

I can make this happen with an Arduino, but am hoping to do something solid-state, reliable and cheap. Plus, it's probably apparent I'm a hack, not an EE, so am open to alternatives and OTS solutions (haven't been able to find toggle to momentary w/ feedback confirmation anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

The momentary switch is probably implemented in firmware with debouncing and other delays, so you'd want to generate a pulse that meets those requirements, plus detecting the current state of the fan with some kind of circuit. And maybe re-try if the desired state does not occur.

It's probably too much for a beginner to find an attractive option, but an 8-pin microcontroller would make short work of this.

Failing that, an Arduino Nano is not a bad compromise for a one-off. It's basically just an MCU with a few support components on board. You'd need some external parts most likely to detect the fan state and simulate the button, neither of which you've given enough information to comment upon.